# How do I dynamically name a property and push objects to it?

Tags: javascript

I am using Angular, and I have the Underscore library available.

```
this.people = {};

var self = this;

var data = { 'name' : 'cool', 'age' : 23 };
```

i want to dynamically create arrays inside the people object, and be able to push data to each of them...

so I thought something like these would work...

```
var arrName = 'group1';

this.people[arrName].push(data);
```

or...

```
this.people[arrName].push(data);
```

I want an object like;

```
people : {
    'group1' : {
        { 'name' : 'test', 'age' : 21 },
        { 'name' : 'test', 'age' : 27 },
        { 'name' : 'test', 'age' : 23 },
    },
    'group2' : {
        { 'name' : 'test2', 'age' : 21 },
        { 'name' : 'testaaa', 'age' : 27 },
        { 'name' : 'testbbb', 'age' : 23 },
    }
}

console.log(self.people);
```

but the 'group1', and 'group2', must be dynamic, and can be created from a variable...

I have attached a jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/2urqvxzh/1/

These will then in turn be stored in LocalStorage and the objects will in all likelihood reach a few hundred items in each array, and there might be up to 50 arrays in people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dynamically create your array like so:

```
var people = {};
var arrName1 = 'group1';

people[arrName1] = []; // here declare an array with [] or new Array()
people[arrName1].push(data); // then you can push
```

Your object will look like this in the end:

```
people : {
    'group1' : [ //group 1 needs to be an array, not an object
        { 'name' : 'test', 'age' : 21 },
        { 'name' : 'test', 'age' : 27 },
        { 'name' : 'test', 'age' : 23 },
    ],
    'group2' : [
        { 'name' : 'test2', 'age' : 21 },
        { 'name' : 'testaaa', 'age' : 27 },
        { 'name' : 'testbbb', 'age' : 23 },
    ]
}
```

An object needs `key/value`, an array has just values. You were thinking about array but created an object.

Comment: The syntax and code suggested does work, and I have turned it into a Fiddle, and it can be found here;  

https://jsfiddle.net/2urqvxzh/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```
var people = {};
var arrName1 = 'group1';
var data = { 'name' : 'cool', 'age' : 23 };

people[arrName1] = new Array(data);
```

Here is a sample JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DivakarDass/2urqvxzh/6/

Your output will be like...

```
people : {
    'group1' : [
        { 'name' : 'test', 'age' : 21 },
        { 'name' : 'test', 'age' : 27 },
        { 'name' : 'test', 'age' : 23 },
    ],
    'group2' : [
        { 'name' : 'test2', 'age' : 21 },
        { 'name' : 'testaaa', 'age' : 27 },
        { 'name' : 'testbbb', 'age' : 23 },
    ]
}
```

Comment: I personally find the code from GreenLeaf as more elegant, as it shows the adding of items to the array, rather than creating the Array just once.

Many thanks though.